# How to convert MVS C++ code into executable application?

Tags: c++

So I've made a small program in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ (2008 edition) and I want to convert it to .exe format.

I know that I can find the .exe in my project directory, however it only runs fine on my own PC. When I send it over to someone else (who doesn't have Visual Studio installed or anything), it doesn't run.

I've read a little about this and it seems to be about "linking". Now I don't know anything about linking and I'm not eager to learn in depth about it right now...

I just want to make my incredibly simple program (which edits and creates text files) to run in .exe program on any computer. Is this possible, and if so - how?

Could you please guide me through the steps? I'm quite new to programming so I really need help on this one.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: did you compile a debug or release version of your code?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins - compiling under release mode does not solve the whole "issue". Some other things should be done, especially if there are 3rd party libs.

Comment: There are no 3rd party libs as far as I know, these are the only libs included:#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

Comment: Fair enough, I guess i should of Asked about static or dynamic linking.

Comment: When you say something "doesn't run" you need to be more specific. What are you seeing? Error messages? Nothing? Frozen? Is it in task manager? Help us help you. Otherwise every answer will be a guess, which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: When the .exe is run, it shows the small black screen (like cmd) and it disappears like within 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

The file you sent already is an exe file, but it is most likely a debug version of the program. Also, you need to see if you are linking against other DLLs, and if you are, you should distribute those with the program as well.

Since you have a simple program, it is most likely you have no other DLL dependencies, so try compiling in release mode as a first step. There will be a dropdown at the top of VS with `Debug` and `Release`, and `Debug` is currently selected.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to actually compile it in release mode. Could you please show me the steps? And when I compile it in the release mode, I look for the .exe file in the exact same place as it was in the debug mode (in the project directory), right?

Comment: Find the dropdown I mentioned with `Debug` selected, click it, and choose `Release`. There is going to be a debug folder and a release folder in your project folder, you were getting the file out of the debug folder before, look for an exe in the release folder after the build.

Comment: I did compile it this way, but I'm not seeing any .exe in my Release directory.

Comment: Are you getting any compilation errors? It could be that you changed the project configuration and changed the output directory for the Release exe. If the output folder for the Debug and Release are the same, one will overwrite the other when you compile, and the EXE you found earlier will now be the release EXE.

Comment: I switched between Code Generation options a bit and I finally got the Release directory with an .exe inside. There's also one more file inside, "Program debug database". Do I need to export this along with my .exe to work, or is .exe enough?

Comment: You should not distribute the PDB file, that will make it easy for others to reverse-engineer your application, and is not required to run the app.

Comment: Thank you Greg, you've helped me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my comment so others can see that it solved (or helped to solve) your problem.

Comment: I will do that, however, I've just sent this .exe to my girlfriend's PC, and it just opens and closes the .exe file in like 0.5 seconds. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can't really offer any explanations. Consider opening another question with that problem description.

Comment: Well I don't see the point of opening another question, since my main problem still remains unsolved... here's my code:http://joggingbenefits.net/hcode.txt

Comment: Could be she needs to run as administrator?

Comment: She is an administrator, so it's not that. This is the error I've been getting all along, even with the debug version. It opens the program, runs for 0.5s and then disappears. Even with antiviruses etc disabled... So it could be that static linking someone was mentioning? But I don't know how to go about doing that...

Answer (score 0):

You already have the .exe file that is created by linking all the .obj files that are compiled from the .cpp files you created. To repeat myself, the linking is already happening behind the scenes. However, there are two other issues. First, you may have compiled it in debug mode. In order to run your program on another Windows machine, it is best to compile it in release mode. Also, if your program uses DLLs, such as for MFC classes, then you need to copy those DLLs to the other computer as well. In order to do this correctly, you should look at creating a `setup.exe` file which will correctly install your program and all the required DLLs. There are tools that can help you do this, such as InstallShield.

Comment: Hi Code-Guru. My program doesn't use any DLLs, so that's not a problem. But I don't actually know how to "compile it in release mode". Could you please explain to me or point me to a source that explains this in an easy-to-undestand manner? Thank you.

Comment: Greg explained how in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries : "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)" required to run applications developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2008 installed.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: It would be ridiculous if every machine that I wanted this program to run on, would have to have Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package installed?

Comment: For such a simple program, perhaps it is a bit of overkill. However, if you are installing multiple programs that use MFC, then using DLLs from the Redistributable Package can save a huge amount of disk space on the other machines. I strongly suggest that you take a little bit of time to research how DLLs work to at least get a broad overview.

Comment: There is a much better solution: you can create an installer by right-click on solution, Add, Project Output. Project + Properties, Prerequisites and tick the "Visual C++ Runtime Libraries (x64)" checkbox.

Comment: @LikBezPujanki: To reinforce what Code-Guru said, read [Advantages of using DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtba4t8b%28v=vs.90%29), particularly the first three bullet points.

Comment: @LikBezPujanki: This is not "ridiculous", this is a must. Every program compiled in VC++2005/2008/2010 needs to have Runtime statically linked or have corresponding Redistributable installed on target machine.

Comment: Okay, how do I link the runtime statically then?

Comment: @SChepurin: It's a must, yes, but the Microsoft requirement is still ridiculous. The logical solution would be to have the CRT DLL behave like all other native DLLs: drop into the same folder as EXE, done. (aka XCOPY deployment).